# Magento Delete particular order from frontend

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to use the following code for deleting order -

```
require 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);                                                                                                                 
//replace your own orders numbers here:
$test_order_id='100000001';

try{
   Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($test_order_id)->delete();
   echo "order #".$test_order_id." is removed".PHP_EOL;
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo "order #".$test_order_id." could not be remvoved: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo "complete."
```

But still I am not getting any success. Please help.

Comment: Still order displaying in Magento Grid.

Comment: Do you get the message "Is removed" or "could not be removed?"

Answer (score 2):

If you echo out the exception that is caught, `$e->getMessage()`, you will probably see the following message:

```
Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.
```

The point that you get to is a function that protects a model from a non secure area.

```
/**
 * Safeguard func that will check, if we are in admin area
 *
 * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
 */
protected function _protectFromNonAdmin()
{
    if (Mage::registry('isSecureArea')) {
        return;
    }
    if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot complete this operation from non-admin area.'));
    }
}
```

For good reason the non-admin site should not be able to delete orders. I can suggest the following.

1. Create a set-up script that deletes the orders for you,
2. Create an admin page that deletes the orders,
3. Set you front-end page as "secure area" with `Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);`

I would suggest that you either work with option 1 or 2 here.

For a set-up script you will need to set the store as admin with the following code.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and try updated this below code

```
  require 'app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);                                                                                                                 
    //replace your own orders numbers here:
    $test_order_id='100000001';

    try{
       Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);
       Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($test_order_id)->delete();
       Mage::unregister('isSecureArea');
       echo "order #".$test_order_id." is removed".PHP_EOL;
    }catch(Exception $e){
       echo "order #".$test_order_id." could not be remvoved: ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    echo "complete."
```